# Detect ovals in image - opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have the below image and I'm trying to detect ovals as highlighted in the image. I tried using findContours() but I couldn't detect them properly. could you please help me?

[image]

[image]

here's my code:

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
ret, image = cv2.threshold(image, 70, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.drawContours(image,cnts,-1,(0,255,255),1)
cv2.imshow('output',image)
```

Comment: In general, your basic idea (thresholding and contour finding) will work, but: (1) Get larger images! Your ovals partly have only 1 pixel distances to each other, so you can't expect any algorithm to distinguish properly between those. (2) You try to detect more or less "dark" objects on "light" background, so you need to use `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`. And - maybe not relevant here since it's not shown - but if your image was loaded using `cv2.imread`, you better use `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` and `cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR`.

Comment: since the shaded ovals are much bigger you could also try performing erosion (morphological operation) or blurring to 'remove' the unshaded ovals from the thresholded image (assuming a binary image).